# Reading serial data in linux byte-for-byte at 56K reliably

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, timeout, buffer

I'm trying to create a function with the most minimal delay possible that checks to see if the serial port has data and if it does, it reads every single byte and prints each byte in hex format until no more bytes are available. If there is no data, the function must return right away.

This is my code:

```
int fd=open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);  

// Trying to set correct options here
struct termios o;
tcgetattr(fd,&o);
cfsetispeed(&o,57600);
cfsetospeed(&o,57600);
/* 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
o.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;o.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;o.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;o.c_cflag |= CS8;
/* no hardware flow control */
o.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
/* enable receiver, ignore status lines */
o.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
/* disable input/output flow control, disable restart chars */
o.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
/* disable canonical input, disable echo, disable visually erase chars, disable terminal-generated signals */
o.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
/* disable output processing */
o.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
o.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; //to prevent delay in read();
o.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &o);
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);

char sp[1]; //hold 1 byte
int bytes=read(fd,sp,1); //Good news: this function doesn't lock
if (bytes > 0){
    //this is never reached even if a byte is 
    //present on the serial line. why?
    printf("Read: ");
    while(bytes > 0){
        printf("%X ",sp[0]);
        bytes=read(fd,sp,1);
    }
}
fclose(fd);
```

Is there a way to fix this?

This whole function (minus the serial port options section) will eventually run in an endless loop as I am constantly scanning my port for data then printing it. Then later I'll add some more functionality where I'll write data to the port at predefined times regardless of what data is received.

P.S. not sure if this is of help, but the target device I'm doing I/O with is custom hardware around an 8051 microcontroller and its serial fifo buffers are only 1 byte whereas the PC's buffers I think are 14 or 16 bytes.

Comment: You are not checking your function return values for errors. Most C functions indicate in one way or another by their return values whether they succeeded or whether an error occurred, and you invite all sorts of mystifying behaviors if you do not check for and handle such errors at every point where they can occur.

Comment: If you intend for the function to run in an endless loop, then why do you need to avoid blocking?  You seem to be making things a lot harder on yourself than they need to be.

Comment: because later I will need to avoid blocking. Like I said, I will eventually send data out on the serial port at predefined times but I don't want that to be held up just because there is no data on the serial port.

Comment: Have you established basic communications?

Comment: The serial control interface supports read timeouts as short as one tenth of one second. If you have timing requirements tighter than that for your periodic outbound messaging then maybe you should be looking into a different communication technology.  Spinning without ever blocking is going to be computationally expensive -- even when not receiving.

Comment: *"Is there a way to fix this?"*"* -- Simply change to  `o.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;`   Per http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html you do not meet the requirement of *"really, really know what you're doing"*.

Comment: @sawdust, since the OP wants to avoid blocking (for long), I'm thinking that leaving `VMIN` at 0 and setting `VTIME` to 1 might be a better bet.  Along with matching that timeout to the transmission rate by making requests for 720 bytes at a time (or more).

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I'm trying to break the limits of the underlying serial hardware (radio modem modules). I decided to switch from the file IO operations on the serial device to just direct I/O access (using inb and outb functions) and I managed to make transmission alone much faster, but the receiving I'm still struggling. I managed to get one correct byte. I'll keep playing around with my code and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Why are you polling?  Is there no asynchronous buffered I/O on Linux?

Comment: @jwdonahue even if there is not, it's fairly trivial to thread off the serial rx. The polling is a nasty bodge, the reading of one char at a time is wasteful of system calls and 56k is a trivial baud rate anyway, for today's hardware.  It should not be necessary to apply kludges like inb/outb assembler loops.  This design is broken:(

Answer (score 2):

If you know beforehand the times when you need to write to the device, you can use [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to wait for input until the next time you wish/intend to write.

A much more simple and robust approach — because your reads and writes are not in a defined sequence, and your hardware is full duplex — is to use separate threads for reading and writing. Basically, you use blocking reads and writes (`c_cc[VMIN] = 1`, `c_cc[VTIME] = 0` for reading, `O_NONBLOCK` *not* among file open flags). You should allow larger buffers, though; reads will return all that have been received thus far, but with those settings wake up the reader whenever there is at least one char received. For writing, I do recommend you do a `tcdrain(fd);` after each write that completes a command/message to the device, to ensure it is sent on the wire by the kernel. (Do remember that writes to the serial port can be short; you need a write loop.)

In all cases, the kernel on the host side will cache data sent and received. Depending on the hardware and driver, even a blocking `write()` may return earlier than when all of the data is actually on the wire. The hardware and the kernel driver, not the host software, is responsible for correct timing of the serial data.

Using one-byte buffer on the host side will not affect the microcontroller at all, you'll just do more syscalls than is necessary, wasting CPU resources and possibly slow down your program a bit. At 57600 baud, with 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit, and the implicit start bit, the actual data rate is 46080 bits/second (±5% typically allowed), or 5760 bytes per second. The microcontroller will always have about 1 s /5760 ≃ 0.0001736 seconds, or over 173 microseconds, to process each incoming byte. (I'd design my firmware to not allow higher priority interrupts etc. to delay processing for more than 100 microseconds or so even in the worst case, to ensure no chars are dropped. If you receive the chars in an interrupt handler, I'd use a small circular buffer, and an indicator character, `\r` or `\n`, so that if such character is received, a flag is raised for the main program to notice that a new complete command has been received. The circular buffer should be long enough to hold two full commands, or more if some commands may take longer to parse/process/handle.)

If the host operating system wakes up the process 1 ms after of receiving the first character, additional four or five characters have arrived in the mean time.  Because this latency can be much higher on some systems, I'd use a much larger buffer, say up to 256 chars, to avoid doing superfluous syscalls when the kernel is for some reason delayed in waking up the reader thread. Yes, it will often read just 1 char, and that is fine; but when the system is overloaded, you don't want to add to that load by doing hundreds of superfluous syscalls when one would suffice.

Remember, the [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) interface, with `VMIN=1, VTIME=0`, will cause the blocking read to be woken up as soon as possible, whenever even a single character is received. It is just that you cannot ensure your program is constantly running, unless you waste about 100% of CPU power by spinning in place (and if you do, nobody will want to run your program). Depending on the system, there may be a delay in waking up the blocking read, during which time more data may be received, so using a larger `read()` buffer is definitely sensible.

Similarly, you can safely use as large writes as you want (up to a limit of about 2 GiB), although most serial drivers can return short counts, so you'll need a loop there anyway. The [`tcdrain(fd)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcdrain.3.html) on the serial port descriptor will block until all written data has been actually transmitted, so you'll probably want to use it. (If you do not, you can just write more data; the kernel driver will take care of the details, and not reorder/mess data up.)

Using two threads, one for reading, one for writing, may sound daunting/odd, but it is actually the simplest way of achieving robust communications. You can even use [`pthread_setcancelstate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcancelstate.3.html), [`pthread_setcanceltype()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcanceltype.3.html) and optionally [`pthread_testcancel()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_testcancel.3.html), to write the thread functions so that you can simply cancel the threads (using [`pthread_cancel()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)) to stop them, even if they have critical sections (like adding a received message to some queue protected by a mutex).

Answer (score 1):

Your program has a variety of problems, many of which have been discussed in comments:

- you do not check the return values of your functions
- you poll the serial port and furthermore perform a system call for every byte read
- you appear to be setting the serial port transmission speed incorrectly, via raw integers instead of the macros reserved for the purpose
- you are using the wrong `printf` format

Here is a modified version of your code that addresses all of those issues.  It's unclear whether this will do exactly what you want, and of course I can't test it on your hardware, but it should be a better place to start:

```
int open_serial(const char *device) {
    int fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);  

    if (fd >= 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Set appropriate serial and line-discipline options
    struct termios o;

    if ((tcgetattr(fd, &o) != 0)
            || (cfsetispeed(&o, B57600) != 0)    // note use of MACRO B57600
            || (cfsetospeed(&o, B57600) != 0)) { //
        return -1;
    }

    /* 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit, no hardware flow control */
    o.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | CSTOPB | CSIZE | CRTSCTS);
    o.c_cflag |= CS8;

    /* enable receiver, ignore status lines */
    o.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;

    /* no software flow control */
    o.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

    /* Operate in raw mode without echo or signaling */
    o.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

    /* disable output processing */
    o.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* Perform pure timed reads */
    o.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    o.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    /* apply the settings, and discard any buffered input */
    if ((tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &o) != 0)
            || (tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH) != 0)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int read_serial(int fd) {
    /*
     * 0.1-sec timed reads of a port running at 56K may read up to 720 bytes each,
     * give or take.  Allow for a few more to account for overhead, etc..
     */
    char sp[768];
    int nr;

    puts("Read: ");
    // Reads will normally block for 0.1 seconds:
    while ((nr = read(fd, sp, sizeof(sp))) != -1) {
        // Any data ready to send can be dispatched now ...

        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {            
            printf("%hhX ", (unsigned char) sp[i]);
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Whats odd is that other sources claim your values of VMIN and VTIME are accurate but for some reason, using your code still makes that while loop go forever as long as there is no incoming data in the serial port. I wonder if I need to patch a C library. hmmm...